# Running Curl POST w/ JSON Payload Sequentially Against File

Tags: bash, curl, post

I am hitting a wall trying to build a script to save myself quite a good bit of time. I am working in a system in which I need to run a curl POST against a list of values. The list is about 400 lines long, so I am hoping to find a way of scripting this in Bash instead of running that call manually for each entry. Below are some details to help understand what I'm trying to accomplish:

If I were to be doing this task manually, each call would be formatted like the below:

```
curl -X POST --header "Content-Type: application/json" -v 'http://www.website.com:8081/cc/membership' -d @json_payload.json
```

This points to my JSON in the listed file which shows as the below:

```
{
    "groupId": "12345678987654321",
    "type": "serial",
    "memberInfo": "apple"
}
```

If I run the above, the call works, and the expected operation occurs. The issue is that I need to run this against roughly 400 values for that "memberInfo" field in the JSON payload. I'm trying to identify a way to run a single bash script, which will run this curl command over and over, and update the JSON payload to use each row in a file as the below:

**memberList.txt**

```
apple
banana
peach
pear
orange
.
.
```

And then maybe insert a pointer in my JSON for the "memberInfo" field over to this file.

Any and all help/suggestions are greatly appreciated!
    .

Answer (score 0):

This will do as you intend. Its a little convoluted but you might polish it a bit.

```
#!/bin/bash

function getString(){
    echo $1 | python3 -c '
import json
import sys

payload="""
        {
            "groupId": "12345678987654321",
            "type": "serial",
            "memberInfo": ""
        }
"""
obj = json.loads(payload)
obj["memberInfo"] =  sys.stdin.read().strip()
print(json.dumps(obj, indent = "    "))
'
}


while read member
do
    getString "$member" > json_payload.json
    curl -X POST --header "Content-Type: application/json" -v 'http://www.website.com:8081/cc/membership' -d @json_payload.json
done <<< "$( cat fruits.txt )"
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
while read member; do
  curl -X POST --header "Content-Type: application/json" -v 'http://www.website.com:8081/cc/membership' -d '{"groupId": "12345678987654321","type": "serial","memberInfo": "$member"}'
done <members.txt
```

This will work if you only care about the memberInfo field, another method could be writing your json line by line to payloads.txt file.
**payloads.txt**

```
{"groupId": "12345678987455432","type": "stereo","memberInfo": "apple"}
{"groupId": "34532453453453465","type": "serial","memberInfo": "banana"}
...
```

then use this as the script

```
while read payload; do
  curl -X POST --header "Content-Type: application/json" -v 'http://www.website.com:8081/cc/membership' -d '$payload'
done <payloads.txt
```

here is a collection of bash scripting common uses I've had to use
https://github.com/felts94/advanced-bash/blob/master/bash_learn.sh

Comment: MoreCoffeeLessJava - I attempted the first version you suggested, in which you type out the JSON payload, but then just assign "$member" for that specific field, which should then fill with each run the value from the "members.txt" file. When I ran this however, the call is actually entering a "memberInfo" field of "$MEMBER". After the first one, I'm being returned with a response stating that "$MEMBER is already a member". Does this value need to be quoted out in a different manner perhaps?

Comment: It sounds like the curl request worked and what you are connecting to responded in turn with an error